# How to tell which packages are available to install using apt-get?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

Using Ubuntu Software Center I can perform a search on an approximate package name and get the matching packages list to select from.

If I work on a remote machine via ssh (i.e. command line only), how do I perform such a search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several options here.

- `apt-cache`, which will search in descriptions too, by default:

  ```
  # keywords or regular expressions
  apt-cache search keyword1 keyword2

  # same, but limits to name of package
  apt-cache search --names-only packagename

  # shows versions available from each repo
  apt-cache policy packagename
  ```
- `aptitude`:

  ```
  aptitude search packagename
  ```

  <sup>`aptitude` has known issues using Multiarch currently, but searching should work though. [LP bug #831768](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/831768)</sup>
- `dpkg`:

  ```
  dpkg -l | grep keyword # inefficient because of useless use of grep

  dpkg -l pattern-of-packagename
  ```
- Online: [`packages.ubuntu.com`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)